# Google sheet conditional formatting if the cell contains ref to another sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Is it possible to create conditional formatting that will color a cell if it contains a reference to a different sheet of the same document?
More generically, is it possible to create a conditional formatting based not on the value of a cell bu on the formula behind a cell?

I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not very clear but if you are after this then it's possible:

[image: 0]

custom formula would be:

```
=ISFORMULA(B1)
```

this would highlight all formulae of course so you will need to further narrow it down for example by using `FORMULATEXT` with regex like:

```
=ISFORMULA(B1)*REGEXMATCH(FORMULATEXT(B1), "^\=[A-Z]\d|^\={[A-Z]\d")
```

[image: 0]

which would not highlight any other formulae like for example `=SUM(1+2)`